# Search the File Pattern from File Name

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file Patter_File.txt which stores lines like below -

```
ABC|ABC_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].dat|8|,|70|NAME

ABC|ABC_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].dat|9|,|70|PLACE

XYZ|XYZ_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].dat|23|,|70|SSN

XYZ|XYZ_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].dat|33|,|70|DOB

MNO|MNO_SUMMIT.dat|40|,|70|ADDRESS

MNO|MNO_SUMMIT.dat|5|,|70|COUNTRY
```

So this PATTERN_FILE.txt stores some information of the actual file but file name is stored in the pattern(if file name has date in the name) except the actual name.

My requirement is a command in which I should pass the actual file name like "ABC_20200408.dat" and it should return all the related lines from this file. Can someone please help.

below command is working fine but in this case I have to pass each pattern one by one to check which one is working.

```
echo "ABC_20200408.dat"|grep ABC_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].dat
```

Comment: So literally `grep` takes an option that allows it to read patterns from a file...

Comment: Can someone provide the command plz